# How to clear a JavaFx TextField with TextFormatter

Tags: javafx, textfield

I got a Double TextField example from some web site. It does work fine, but I have two problems:

1. The TextFormatter constructor requires a default value if one wants to have both a converter and a filter. I would like that default value NOT to be displayed when I launch the application but could not find how to do it.
2. I added to the example a button to clear the two TextFields, this triggers a NullPointerException when executing textField.clear(); how to I clear such a TextField?

Here is the code:

```
package sample;

import java.util.function.UnaryOperator;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

public class DoubleFieldExample extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        final TextField field = new TextField();
        final TextField field2 = new TextField();
        final Button clearBtn = new Button("Clear Text Fields");
        final Double defaultValue = 0.5;

        final UnaryOperator<TextFormatter.Change> numberOnlyFilter = change -> {
            final String text = change.getText();
            return (text.isEmpty() || text .matches("[0-9.eE+-]")) ? change : null;
        };

        final StringConverter<Double> NumberConverter = new StringConverter<Double>() {
            @Override
            public String toString(Double value) {
                return (value == null) ? null : value.toString();
            }
            @Override
            public Double fromString(String text) {
                return (text == null || text.trim().isEmpty()) ? null : Double.parseDouble(text.trim());
            }
        };

        final TextFormatter<Double> numberOnlyFormatterField1 = new TextFormatter<Double>(NumberConverter, defaultValue, numberOnlyFilter);
        final TextFormatter<Double> numberOnlyFormatterField2 = new TextFormatter<Double>(NumberConverter, defaultValue, numberOnlyFilter);
        field.setTextFormatter(numberOnlyFormatterField1);
        field2.setTextFormatter(numberOnlyFormatterField2);
        numberOnlyFormatterField1.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> System.out.printf("%s -> %s%n", oldValue, newValue));
        clearBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                field.clear();
                field2.clear();
            }
        });
        final StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().addAll(new VBox(field, field2, clearBtn));
        final Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Test");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the null pointer exception: clearing the text fields works just fine.

Comment: I run it under IntelliJ IDEA / Windows 10.

Comment: Which Java/JavaFX versions?

Comment: Ah, OK, I see the NPE running under JavaFX/JDK 8. It works fine in 11 and later.

Comment: I moved to file to its own package, produced a jar file. When I run it from the IDEA I get the null pointer exception, but the program does not stop. When I run it from Windows Explorer it works just fine !!!   Is it normal ?.

Comment: It probably means you're running with different JDK/JavaFX versions: see the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the text to `null` via the text formatter's converter causes a null pointer exception in JavaFX version 8, but not in later versions (it works fine in version 11 and later: I am not sure in which exact version the issue was fixed).

In any case, you can avoid doing this by representing a `null` value as an empty string, instead of a `null` string:

```
    final StringConverter<Double> NumberConverter = new StringConverter<Double>() {
        @Override
        public String toString(Double value) {
            // return (value == null) ? null : value.toString();
            return (value == null) ? "" : value.toString();
        }
        @Override
        public Double fromString(String text) {
            return (text == null || text.trim().isEmpty()) ? null : Double.parseDouble(text.trim());
        }
    };
```

With this fix, you can now make the default value `null` instead of some arbitrary value, which will initialize the text fields as empty:

```
    final Double defaultValue = null;
```

Comment: I also need help on how to formulate the regex to get a field that would only accept positive double numbers

Comment: @user2784655 That's something of a different question: so you should post another question (and accept this answer if it solves the original problem).